# nodejs how I can find out how old a Domain is?

Tags: node.js

I want to check how old a domain is.

With whois it works only with .com sites (`npm install whois`)

But German sites like test.de do not work.

```
const whois = require('whois');

const data = async domain => {
      const data = await whois(domain);

      return console.log(data);
  }

   console.log(data('web.de'));
```

Comment: when I run your code I receive whois is not a function.
I tried the function lookup which works for web.de

Comment: You have to install whois with NPM. And show me the script with lookup please